# Generics gone wrong

Tags: java

```
public class Ctrl {
    LinkedStack<T> x = new LinkedStack<T>();
```

I'm trying to use generics for the first time and I get the error "Multiple markers at this line - T cannot be resolved to a type" for the line above.What am I not doing right?

```
public class LinkedStack<E> {
    private static class LinkedNode<T> 
    {
        private T item;
        private LinkedNode<T> next;

        private LinkedNode(T value) 
        {
            item = value;
            next = null;
        }

            private LinkedNode(T value, LinkedNode<T> reference) 
            {
                item = value;
                next = reference;
            }
        }
 protected LinkedNode<E> top;
    public LinkedStack() 
    {
        top = null;     // empty stack
    }
```

Comment: You are using `T` as an argument, but it isn't declared anywhere (that we can see).

Comment: `T` is the name of the type parameter. You need to provide an actual type (e.g., `Integer`, `Object`, etc.)

Comment: Do you intend `Ctrl` to be a generic class?  If so, the declaration should be `public class Ctrl<T> { ` etc.

Comment: Generics is one of the things that is really hard to get right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the same type parameter name everywhere.

Then add it to your `Ctrl` class as a parameter.

```
public class Ctrl<T> {
    LinkedStack<T> x = new LinkedStack<T>();
```

Now all concrete implementations must define `T`. For example:

```
public class AppCtrl extends Ctrl<Integer> {
}
```

Or instantiate it with a concrete type.

```
Ctrl myctrl = new Ctrl<Integer>();// + necessary constructor params
```

Or if you don't want to pass it, specify it directly inside `Ctrl`

```
public class Ctrl {
        LinkedStack<Integer> x = new LinkedStack<Integer>();
```